# Want to Open and then close the same window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am working on a project in which i need to open a new window when a button/link is clicked. and then close it after waiting for a second. Problem is that I want the window to stay open for at least a second. I am able to open and close the window, but the switching is so quick that it defeating the purpose of opening the window in the first place.

I have also looked into setTimeout to create delay, but then again, I believe i m not using it properly. This is how i m doing it right now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function myPopup() {
       window.open( "http://arduino.local/arduino/digital/12/1", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
       window.close();
     }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" onClick="myPopup()" value="POP!">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
function myPopup() {
  var myWin = window.open( "http://arduino.local/arduino/digital/12/1", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
  setTimeout(function() { myWin.close(); }, 2000); // 2 second delay
}
```